# One class classifier for fraud call detection ( in Hindi language) using BERT

Tags: nlp, data-science-model, bert

I have created a dataset of text files that are nothing but transcripts of fraud call recordings. I want to implement one class classifier as I have only fraud call audio and transcripts but not a single normal(not fraud) call recording. I want to use BERT's multilanguage model but I don't know intermediate steps or resources for such a project.  Can anyone help me with the approach? thank you.

Comment: Do you want to predict if the call is fraud or not?

Comment: yes, but only with single labeled data.

Comment: it means you don't have any label, a column with one value is useless. 
Try to add some not fraud data to it.